# Every now and then (quicker movement)

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7, xna

I have made a little game in C# and would like to modify the movement of the AI characters a little bit.

Right now, they are programmed to just follow the player control (it's one of those games where the AI chars follow you around, and they keep multiplying and you have to avoid them in order to survive). But what I would like to do is *every now and then*, make the closest AI character *quickly jump** closer toward the player (me).

*When I say jump I don't mean literally. I mean, I want the AI char to just increase its speed for about 20 - 40 pixels (making it appear to have jumped closer to the player, or ran faster toward the player).

How can I do this?

I have thought about implementing a timer and in the Update method get the closest AI to the player and increase its speed, but I am also thinking there has to be a better way than to use a timer.

Comment: What is your code? Also, timer **is** what you want.

Comment: Why does a timer seem wrong.  You want to execute some code every X interval of time.  That's literally what a timer is built to do.  Now if you find yourself with lots and lots of timers, thats a red flag; in such cases consider making a queue of things to do (ordered by time to go do them) and have just one timer that handles the next item in the queue.

Comment: Yeah use a timer. To get 'Every now and then' one solution would be to roll a random (say, out of 3) when it ticks, and if a 2 comes up then do the action.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a timer and an event handler, though a really fun way to do it would be to randomly set the interval each time the timer fires. Unless you keep track of the distance continuously for each AI to the player, you'll need to calculate this every time the event fires. Fortunately, a few simple distance formula calculations go pretty quick. You don't even need to take the square root (which is a performance killer), since you just need to see who is closest. After determining the closest one, just increase their velocity for a bit. Maybe keep a global pointer to the last_updated character, so that every time you update a player's velocity - you will return the previously updated player's velocity to normal.

Assuming your code is object oriented, i find it best to keep track of both a position and velocity for each player - and then simply call an update method on them that will move their position according to their velocity. This would make this problem trivial, since after determining the closest player all you would need to do is slightly increase their velocity ;)

Setting the timer's interval randomly will also prevent you from getting lots of timer events that won't actually do anything. This way every time the timer fires, you will be making a change to the game. That should settle your nerves about using a timer.